# Using custom attr to add css?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a generic CSS banner code with a little CSS3 animation (Not the point, but providing background). What I'm trying to achieve is setting the banner class with a custom attribute and getting that attributes content and using jQuery to append a style with it? Like so, However their is alot of these divs that will be using the same technique on the same page...

```
<div class="banner banner-small animate" data-bg="https://domain.com/path/img/bg.png">
    ....
</div>
```

Then jQuery would run and output the code like...

```
<div class="banner banner-small animate" data-bg="https://domain.com/path/img/bg.png" style="background-image: url('https://domain.com/path/img/bg.png')">
    ....
</div>
```

I hope that this wasn't to vague. I've only recently started learning jQuery and I'm loving it! Just don't really know how to go around doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, there are a variety of ways that you can use data attributes as selectors and then access their data via the [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) function :

```
// Iterate through each element with the data-bg attribute
$('[data-bg]').each(function(){
     // Set the background image for each element to it's respective
     // attribute value
     $(this).css('background-image','url(' + $(this).data('bg') + ')');
});
```

Or if you don't want to invoke jQuery twice, you can use [Niet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/niet-the-dark-absol)'s suggestion:

```
$('[data-bg]').each(function(){
     this.style.backgroundImage = url(' + this.getAttribute('data-bg') + ')';
});
```

Or the following one from [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo), which forgoes an explicitly loop entirely:

```
$('[data-bg]').css('background-image', function() {
     return 'url(' + $(this).data('bg') + ')';
});
```

Comment: Personal nitpick: Use `this.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+this.getAttribute('data-bg')+')';` instead of invoking jQuery twice ;)

Comment: Thanks - Worked like a charm!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I've added your option as well :)